# Disable certain field in Go mongo bson map

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, go, bson, mongo-go

I'm using `"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"`
Is there a way to be able to disable a field, but still a valid bson map?

```golang
publishFilter := bson.M{}

if publishedOnly {
    publishFilter = bson.M{"published": true}
}

pipeline := []bson.M{
    {"$sort": bson.M{"_id": -1}},
    {
        "$match": bson.M{
            "_id": bson.M{
                "$gt":  sinceObjectID,
                "$lte": maxObjectID,
            },
            publishFilter, // I want to control this to be nothing or `{"published": true}`
            // depending on `publishedOnly`
        },
    },
    {"$limit": query.Count},
}
```

This snippet definitely not compile `Missing key in map literal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "disable" fields in a map, but you can build the `$match` document conditionally:

```
matchDoc := bson.M{
    "_id": bson.M{
        "$gt":  sinceObjectID,
        "$lte": maxObjectID,
    },
}

if publishedOnly {
    matchDoc["published"] = true
}

pipeline := []bson.M{
    {"$sort": bson.M{"_id": -1}},
    {"$match": matchDoc},
    {"$limit": query.Count},
}
```